# Linux to Windows file

Tags: windows, linux, transfer

I want to copy 2 files from my Linux VM (running in Hyper V) over to the Windows machine it runs in. What is the quickest and simplest way to do this? A lot of pages online use winScp but offer no explanation of how to connect to Linux (after a brief look).

Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: scp is fully supported on Linux so you can use that. You would probably do better to ask on serverfault for how to use scp

Answer (score 1):

Use a flash drive if you have one.

Comment: This is by far simplest option @RossAlexander

Answer (score 1):

You can use SCP only if:

1. You have enabled some sort of networking for your VM
2. You're running sshd (secure shell daemon) on the VM

Assuming you have these two things, you would use WinSCP something like the following (sorry I've only used pscp, which is about identical to scp):

```
winscp root@linuxip:/path/to/file localfile
```

where `linuxip` = the IP address of your VM.

If this is something you have to do often, I would recommend trying to mount a shared drive between the VM and the host.

Answer (score 0):

1) mounting a shared drive thru samba

2) install a windows SSH client/server to use scp

Other solutions are available, but become too complicated. A shared drive would be the best solution, as you can easily use it later on.

By the way, you can use [PCSP](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/dowanload.html) to achieve the second solution : http://techie-buzz.com/tips-and-tricks/upload-files-to-linux-from-windows-using-pscp.html

Answer (score 0):

You can copy any files with scp(linux) oder pscp(windows) from any other host with a running ssh-server
    `scp/pscp -P [port] [username]@[host]:/[pathtofile]/[file] [localfilename]`

Answer (score 0):

winscp should be fairly self explainatory ?

- download it
- install it
- start it
- Make a new connection
- enter the IP address of your linux box, and the username/password of a user you have on your linux.
- drag/drop files

All this assumes you have set up linux so it has an IP address, and a user/password(many distros lets you log in on the root account by default too.. and afaik all distros starts the ssh service by default - needed for connecting with scp) you can log in as.